# Android - Write byte array to OutputStreamWriter

Tags: android, string, stream, byte

I have an application that uploads photos through a web service.  In the past, I loaded a file into a stream, and converted to Base64.  Then I posted the resulting string through the write() method of an OutputStreamWriter.  Now, the web service has changed, and it expects multipart/form-data and it does not expect Base64.

So somehow I need to post the chararters of this file as is without conversion.  I'm sure I'm close, but all I ever get is a content lengh underflow or overflow.  The odd thing is that in the debugger I can see that my buffer length is the same length as the string I'm posting.  Here's what I'm doing and hopefully enough code:

```
// conn is my connection
OutputStreamWriter dataStream = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

// c is my file
int bytesRead = 0;
long bytesAvailable = c.length();

while (bytesAvailable > 0) {
   byte[] buffer = new byte[Math.min(12288, (int)bytesAvailable)];
   bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, Math.min(12288, (int)bytesAvailable));

   // assign the string if needed.
   if (bytesRead > 0) {
      bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

      // I've tried many encoding types here.
      String sTmp = new String(buffer, "ISO-8859-1");
      // HERE'S the issue.  I can't just write the buffer,
      dataStream.write(sTmp);
      dataStream.flush();
// Yes there's more code, but this should be enough to show why I don't know what I'm doing!
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you convert the bytes to strings instead of writing them raw into the output stream?

Comment: Because the write() method of OutputStreamWriter accepts char[] or string.  Not byte[].

Comment: Try using a `DataOutputStream` instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

change

```
OutputStreamWriter dataStream = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
```

with this

```
DataOutputStream dataStream = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
```

and directly call `dataStream.write(buffer);`

let me know how it behave

Edit: edited answer according to comment

Comment: 'conn' is an HttpURLConnection.  getOutputStream() does not return a 'DataOutputStream', nor can it be casted.

Comment: Ugh sorry.  Need coffee.
DataOutputStream dataStream = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

Comment: Be cautious with this. Although it will allow you to write a byte[] to the output, the other methods of DataOutputStream are not compatible with OutputStremWriter. In particular, OutputStreamWriter can be given a standard encoding for writing Strings, where DataOutputStream has it's own proprietary encodings.